# How to reload UIPageViewController to reload its views in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, swift2

I am using Page Controller embeded in Table VC. Table VC shows details of items and also contains collection view controller as embedded
 one. So now when I select any Collection cell it should display the selected cell item details.
I am able to show everything for the new selected item but Page VC is not getting reloaded as per selected item images, it is still showing the last item images.
SO I'm stuck there. I am attaching the code for Page VC and Detail Table View
Please let me know the approach here to deal with it. Thanks in Advance.!!

```
//-----PAGE VC CODE------
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol ProductImagesPageVCDelegate: class
{
    func setupPageController(numberOfPages: Int)
    func turnPageController(to index: Int)
}

class ProductImagesPageVC: UIPageViewController {

    var product: Product!

    weak var pageViewControllerDelegate: ProductImagesPageVCDelegate?

    struct StoryBoard {
        static let productImageVC = "ProductImageVC"
    }

    lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        if let imageLinks = self.product.imageLinks
        {
            for imageLink in imageLinks
            {
                let productImageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.productImageVC)
                controllers.append(productImageVC)
            }
        }

        self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)

        return controllers
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
//            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
//        } else {
//            automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
//        }
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self

        self.turnToPage(index: 0)


    }


    func turnToPage(index: Int)
    {
        let controller = controllers[index]
        var direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward

        if let currentVC = viewControllers?.first
        {
            guard let currentIndex = controllers.index(of: currentVC) else {return}
            if currentIndex > index
            {
                direction = .reverse
            }
        }

        self.configuewDisplaying(viewController: controller)

        setViewControllers([controller], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func configuewDisplaying(viewController: UIViewController)
    {
        for (index, vc) in controllers.enumerated()
        {
            if viewController === vc {
                if let productImageVC = viewController as? ProductImageVC
                {
                    productImageVC.imageLink = self.product.imageLinks?[index]

                    self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.turnPageController(to: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

extension ProductImagesPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController)
        {
            if index < controllers.count - 1
            {
                return controllers[index + 1]
            }
        }


        return controllers.first
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController)
        {
            if index > 0
            {
                return controllers[index - 1]
            }
        }

        return controllers.last
    }
}

extension ProductImagesPageVC: UIPageViewControllerDelegate
{

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {

        self.configuewDisplaying(viewController: pendingViewControllers.first as! ProductImageVC)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

        if !completed
        {
            self.configuewDisplaying(viewController: previousViewControllers.first as! ProductImageVC)
        }
    }



}
//-----------Tabel VIEW Controllers-----
import UIKit

class ProductDetailTVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var productImagesHeaderView: ProductImagesHeaderView!
    var product: Product!
    var products: [Product]?
    private var selectedProduct: Product?
    struct Storyboard {

        static let productDetailCell = "ProductDetailCell"
        static let buyButtonCell = "BuyButtonCell"
        static let showProductDetailCell = "ShowProductDetailCell"
        static let suggestionTableCell = "SuggestionTableCell"
        static let showImagesPageVC = "ShowProductImagesPageVC"
        static let showProductDetail = "ShowProductDetail"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = product.name
        fetchProducts()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }
    func fetchProducts()
    {
        Product.fetchProducts { (products) in
            self.products = products
            if let index = self.products?.index(where: {$0 === self.product}) {
                self.products?.remove(at: index)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }




    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 4
    }


    fileprivate func extractedFunc() -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.productDetailCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDetailCell

            cell.product = product
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell

        } else if indexPath.row == 1
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.buyButtonCell, for: indexPath) as! BuyButtonCell

            cell.product = product
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell

        } else if indexPath.row == 2
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.showProductDetailCell, for: indexPath)
             cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell

        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.suggestionTableCell, for: indexPath) as! SuggestionTableCell
            //cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell

        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row == 3
        {
            return tableView.bounds.width + 68
        }
        else
        {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }


    //Mark: - UITabeleViewDelegate

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 3
        {
            if let cell = cell as? SuggestionTableCell
            {
                cell.collectionView.delegate = self
                cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
                cell.collectionView.reloadData()
                cell.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }






    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == Storyboard.showImagesPageVC
        {
            if let imagesPageVC = segue.destination  as? ProductImagesPageVC
            {
                imagesPageVC.product = product

                imagesPageVC.pageViewControllerDelegate = productImagesHeaderView
            }
        }
    }


}


//MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
extension ProductDetailTVC : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SuggestionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SuggestionCollectionViewCell

        guard let products = products else {return cell}
        let randomProduct = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(products.count)))
        cell.product = products[randomProduct]


        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let selectedProduct = products?[indexPath.item] else {return}
        self.selectedProduct = selectedProduct
        self.product = selectedProduct
        navigationItem.title = selectedProduct.name

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        collectionView.reloadData()
        self.reloadInputViews()

    }


}


//MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

extension ProductDetailTVC : UICollectionViewDelegate
{

}


//MARK: - UICOLLECTIONVIEWDELEGATEFLOWLAYOUT

extension ProductDetailTVC : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        {
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2.5

            let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width - 5.0) / 2.0

            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
        }

        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone can suggest solution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want it to change when you update the `product` property?

You'll need to add a `didSet` to the property which updates the currently displayed view controller.

Comment: yes.. I need to change the images on page vc of new product

Comment: can u please highlight which part of code of lines u referring to modify

Comment: Anyone can help here

Comment: Can you suggest something? @clever